# Load data in each client

Tags: tensorflow-federated

everyone:

I try to load the `'/root/.tff/emnist_all.sqlite'` in the federated processes. Into the example I can find, only see the local simulation.

```py
    print('### CLIENT_DATA')  
    database_path = '/root/.tff/emnist_all.sqlite'
    client_data = sql_client_data.SqlClientData(database_path, 'digits_only_train').preprocess(_add_proto_parsing).datasets
```

but this is only loading server data (simulation client data).

I think that is necessary to use `federated_map` to load each dataset by the client. I'm a little lost.

Could everyone help me, please?

The rest of the code (summary) is:

```py
    print('### GET CHANNELS')
    # set up the remote executors
    channels = get_channels(list_host)
    tff.backends.native.set_remote_execution_context(channels)
    
    print('### TRAINER')
    trainer = tff.learning.build_federated_averaging_process(model_fn, client_optimizer_fn=lambda: tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.01))
    
    print('### EVALUATE')
    evaluate(trainer, preprocessed_data_for_clients)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, it maybe helpful to think of the dataset (or `tf.data.Dataset`) as a "recipe for creating data iterators" (not really the dataset itself), rather unlike a `numpy.ndarray` or `pandas.DataFrame`. The data is lazily loaded, doesn't become available until something starts working on the dataset (e.g. a `for batch in dataset:` loop). `tf.data.Datasets` that are backed by files generally encode the filepath in the graph that is sent to clients to execute.

Now, `SqlClientData` is a wrapper around `tf.data.Dataset` construction. Its mainly used for simulating FL on a fixed, centralized set of proxy data. The main method used is `SqlClientData.create_tf_dataset_for_client`, which creates [`tf.data.experimental.SqlDataset`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/experimental/SqlDataset) objects. These encode the `database_path` in the computation, which instructs the client where to read its dataset from. This means when the client is about to execute the training loop on the `SqlDataset` in the graph it received, it will look at the path that was encoded in the graph; which will be `'/root/.tff/emnist_all.sqlite'`.

Instead, when constructing a "dataset recipe" on the server, we could try pointing to a path on the clients. A very naive example could be something like:

```py
training_process = tff.learning.build_federated_averaging_process(...)

state = training_process.initialize()
federated_datasets = [
  tf.data.TFRecordDataset('/path/to/client1.tfrecords'),
  tf.data.TFRecordDataset('/path/to/client2.tfrecords'),
  tf.data.TFRecordDataset('/path/to/client3.tfrecords'),
]
state, metrics = training_process(state, federated_datasets)
```

Then we would want to setup each remote worker to have locally accessible TFRecord files at `/path/to/client1.tfrecords`, `/path/to/client1.tfrecords`, and `/path/to/client3.tfrecords`.

Comment: Mr. Z.Garrett, Thank you very much for your response. I will work with this to see if I can make progress. I will keep the thread going with what I find.

Best regards,

Comment: Mr @zachary-garrett, can you give me a hint on how to transform a ClientData to TFRecord, please?

Thank you very much in advance.